# Bootstrap Carousal prev/next controls not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to create a simple bootstrap carousal with 4 pictures. The images are being changed automatically 
but the prev/next controls are not working. Any suggestion will be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000,
  pause: false
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade col-offset-2" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Chania">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Flower">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/JoeZ11/27whk5px/1/

Comment: Please, do not link to external website and provide example of your problem in the proper way.

Comment: @JoeZ please provide jsfiddle or codepen? thanks

Comment: Not sure about browser you use, but it works fine for me (firefox,chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/27whk5px/2/

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rkdrhbg/1/)

or run code snippet below:

```js
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000,
  pause: false
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
    .carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
              transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6F0CE738-6419-4CF4-8E8878246C2D2569.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg" alt="Chania">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/6775415-beautiful-images.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img style="width:675px;height:350px;" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/background-gmail-google-images_FG2XwaO.jpg" alt="Flower">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```